# Import 'TikTokApi' could not be resolved error even though I have TikTokApi installed via pip

Tags: python, import, tiktok

I'm encountering an issue where I'm getting an "Import 'TikTokApi' could not be resolved" error, even though I have the 'tiktokapi' package installed via pip. I have double-checked the installation, and it appears to be successful. However, when I try to import the 'TikTokApi' module in my Python code, I still receive this error.

Is there anything else I can do to troubleshoot this error? Are there any potential conflicts or other factors that may be causing this problem?
My VS Code screen:

[image]

I have tried restarting my environment and verifying the package installation, but the issue persists.

Comment: I'm going to guess that VS Code is using some other version of python on your computer.  Run this code and show us the output `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: Brian, there really was other version of python on my computer. I've uninstalled everything and installed the most recent stable version. You've really reached the point of the error I was experiencing. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.